# Room db - order by alias not working in query with group by

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am having this simple entity

```
@Entity
data class WebpageVisit(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long?,
    val url: String,
    val domain: String,
    val visitTimestamp: Long,
    val visitsCount: Int)
```

and i am trying to run this simple query

```
    @Query("SELECT *, count(*) as visitsCount from webpagevisit group by domain order by visitsCount desc")
    abstract fun getTopWebsites(): LiveData<List<WebpageVisit>>
```

The problem is that the result is not ordered. The data are grouped together correctly, the visitsCount value is correct, but the data are not ordered.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the order like ASC or DESC the way you want.
For ascending order,

```
SELECT Column1,Column2, count(*) as visitsCount from webpagevisit group by domain order by count(*) ASC
```

For descending order,

```
SELECT Column1,Column2, count(*) as visitsCount from webpagevisit group by domain order by count(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. There is 'desc' missing. But adding it makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: Yozoooo, You have to define all columns that you want to get from the table instead of *. Please check updated query. Hope that helps.

Comment: It works, i dont know why, but it works. Thank you Dhaval.

Answer (score 0):

`Group by` and `order by` do not work together when you have `count`, `sum`, `min`, `max` functions in select

Use two separate queries 1 for `count` and second for data `group by` and `order by`.